# Python speech_recognition.UnknownValueError

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I'm trying to make a virtual assistant, right now it's suppost to just write down what I say. However when I try to test it it returns,

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danieldossantos/Desktop/jarvis/chats/main.py", line 14, in 
    speech = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'pt')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/**init**.py", line 858, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError

I've checked my code and I haven't found any errors, at least not that I know of,

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as s:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(s)

    while True:
        audio = r.listen(s)

        speech = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'pt')

        print('Você disse: ', speech)
```

Comment: you got any solution for this `r.recognize_google(audio)` ??? i got the same error too.

Comment: No not yet. I'll let you know if I find one.

Comment: any luck yet???

Answer (score 1):

yes, for me now its working. The problem was with audio ports, as most of our laptop have 2 ports :

**1. audio out** (Green colour)

**2. microphone** (pink colour)

- You need to put your headphone jack in **Audio out** so that it can accept your speech as input.
- As Your code is unable to get any input it returns error saying empty list **[]**

`get("alternative", [])) == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from os import walk

r = sr.Recognizer()
#optional
#r.energy_threshold = 300

def startConvertion(path = 'file.wav', lang = 'en-IN'): 
    with sr.AudioFile(path) as source:
        #print('Fetching File')
        audio_file = r.record(source)
        print(r.recognize_google(audio_file, language=lang))
startConvertion()
```